# Setting wildcard in LIKE CQL filter brakes the filter

Tags: openlayers-3

This is my filter in Openlayers 3.9.0

```
var cqlFilter = "name='testpoint9'";
var urlTemplate =  'http://localhost:5550/geoserver/mymap/wfs?


var sourceVector = new ol.source.Vector({
service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=mymap:layer&CQL_FILTER={{CQLFILTER}}&outputFormat=application/json';
loader : function (extent) {
        var url = urlTemplate.replace('{{CQLFILTER}}', cqlFilter);
        $.ajax(url, {
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(response) {
                var res = response.responseText;
                var geojsonFormat = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
                sourceVector.addFeatures(geojsonFormat.readFeatures(response));
            }
        })
    };

strategy : new ol.loadingstrategy.tile(ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({maxZoom: 20}));
})

function changeFilter() {
    var featsToRemove = layerVector.getSource().getFeatures();
    for (var f=0;f<featsToRemove.length;f++)
    {
        layerVector.getSource().removeFeature(featsToRemove[f]);
    }
    cqlFilter = "name LIKE 'p'";
    sourceVector.clear(true);

}
```

`changeFilter` function gets called after a user hits a button. Changes the `cqlFilter` global variable and reloads features.

The problem is that the CQL filter works now `"name LIKE 'p'"` , but if I try to add a wildcard, to find names that start with p `"name LIKE 'p%'"` this wont work, and I also dont get any error messages.

How do I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use the encodeURIComponent function for you cql filter. like so:

`cqlFilter = "name LIKE 'p%'";
encodedFilter = encodeURIComponent(cqlFilter);`

Comment: Thought it was a filter-related thing. Thanks